# Variable lost after AsyncTasks, exactly in onPostExecute()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my activity i call `getAllDisponibilita()` and i override `onResult()` and `onError()` to make anything after task has been executed. I declare a variable `int a=0` outside method and i increment it in method. If i print the variable in onResult() the value is increased but if i print the variable outside onResult() the value is 0. Why?

This is `getAllDisponibilita()`: a "Data Access Object" method that i use to get data from database, this method is in DisponibilitaDao class.

```
public static void getAllDisponibilita(  final List<JSONObject> jsonList,
                                         final OnRestApiResultListener onRestApiResultListener)  {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>() {

        private String errorMessage = null;

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            Log.d("LOL", "Get All Disponibilita...");
            RestApiResource disponibilitaResource = new RestApiResource() {
                @Override
                public String getResourcePath() { return "disponibilita.json"; }
                @Override
                public String getResourceID() { return ""; }
            };

            int rows = 0;
            RestApiParam params[] = {  };
            RestApiClient client = new RestApiClient();
            try {
                JSONArray array = client.get(disponibilitaResource, params, true);
                for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                    jsonList.add(array.getJSONObject(i));
                }
                rows = 1;
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                errorMessage = e.getMessage();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return rows;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer rows) {
            super.onPostExecute(rows);
            if ( errorMessage != null )
                onRestApiResultListener.onError(errorMessage);
            else
                onRestApiResultListener.onResult(rows);
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

This is my Activity

```
int a =0;
DisponibilitaDao.getAllDisponibilita(listDisponibilita, new OnRestApiResultListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Integer result) {
         a++;
         //IF HERE I PRINT "a" IT IS INCREASED
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String message) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
           //IF HERE I PRINT "a" IT IS 0
```

Comment: It's because a hasn't incremented yet when placed outside of onresult.

Comment: Sure `//IF HERE I PRINT "a" IT IS 0` line executed before `onResult ` method that's why getting `0` when print it after call of `getAllDisponibilita ` method

Comment: Im seeing a lack of knowledge about async process...

Comment: How can i print the increased value outside onResult()? Actually i have an HashMap in place of variable "a" and in this HashMap i put some values that i get from getAllDisponibilita. How can i use this values outside onResult()?

Comment: It's really Nanoc... can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Calling getAllDisponibilita will start the AsyncTask which is a separate thread which runs in parallel to your main ui thread. The main ui thread (the one that called getAllDisponibilita) will continue it's execution with the "//IF HERE I PRINT "a" IT IS 0" code while the AsyncTask thread is processing doInBackground and then onPostExecute (the latter again on the ui thread).

Since executing the AsyncTask code takes some time it's very likely that a hasn't been incremented yet when you print its value in the main ui thread (good example if a race condition...). That's the nature of asynchronous processing. There's no other way to make sure that a has been incremented than to read it in the onResult method.

If you have two AsyncTasks putting their results in a HashMap and you need to wait for both AsyncTasks to finish before processing the results, then that would be considered a join (see also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html).

In this case however I would simply create a method that checks whether both getAllDisponibilita and getAllRichieste have terminated and if yes process whatever code you want to process based on the two results. If the results aren't available yet simply do nothing. You would call this method from the two onResult methods and it has to be synchronized. Something along those lines:

```
private boolean mResultsProcessed;

mResultsProcessed = false;

getAllDisponibilita(listDisponibilita, new OnRestApiResultListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Integer result) {
            checkResult();
        }
    });

getAllRichieste(xyz, new OnRestApiResultListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Integer result) {
            checkResult();
        }
    });

private synchronized void checkResult() {
    if (! mResultsProcessed && hasAllDisponibilitaResults() && hasAllRichiesteResult()) {
       // do whatever you need to do
         mResultsProcessed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all: thanks. Your explaination is very full. Actually i have an HashMap (in place of variable "a") and in it i put some values that i get from getAllDisponibilita. Then i get some other values from another method "getAllRichieste" and i put these values in HashMap.
At the end i want compare this values...

Comment: Thanks. Now i try this solution but i don't know how check if both methods have terminated. I don't understand hasAllDisponibilitaResults() and hasAllRichiesteResult()

Comment: You know what results the two methods/AsyncTasks produce right? You should therefore be able to check if these results have actually been produced. Maybe you need a flag (boolean) for each AsyncTasks that is set when they have terminated.